# Browser not rendering updated values after callback function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a callback function after an animation, and I'm getting a result that I don't understand.

The reader's current_state should increase by 1, then the reader should move right, and then this should repeat 3 more times.

When I run the program using my web inspector, I see that the current_state does indeed increase before moving each step. However, in my browser window I only see the reader's text change values during the first step. So when the program ends, I see a 2 in the reader's text on my screen, but the value of the reader's current_state is actually 5.

To perplex me even more, I was tinkering around and added a random button with an empty click event attached. Hitting this button will make the current_state appear as the reader's text on the screen. So if I repeatedly click this button while the program runs, it looks perfect.

*I'm not looking for an entirely different way to do this, as this isn't my actual code, just an example to illustrate the issue.* In my code I'm trying to stick to using angular and a recursive callback function after an animation, if it's possible to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance, this has been driving me crazy!

https://jsfiddle.net/snookieordie/ns09cvqc/7/

```
var app = angular.module("turingApp", []);

app.controller("turingController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.reader = {
        current_state: 1,
    }

    $scope.run_program = function() {
        if($scope.reader.current_state < 5) {
            $scope.reader.current_state++;
            $(".reader").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, 1000, function() {
                $scope.run_program();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.reader {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 35px;
    background-color: coral;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="turingApp" ; ng-controller="turingController">
    <div class="reader">{{reader.current_state}}</div>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="button" class="code_submit" value="Run Code" ng-click="run_program()" /> 
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Empty Click Event" ng-click="" />
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm.  Yeah.  I'm able to reproduce the issue.  Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/1v0kk9fj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$scope.apply()` just after animate call back function is being called, Below I have edited **js code**

```
var app = angular.module("turingApp", []);

app.controller("turingController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.reader = {
    current_state: 1,
  }

  $scope.run_program = function() {

    if ($scope.reader.current_state < 5) {

      $scope.reader.current_state++;
      $(".reader").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, 1000, function() {
        $scope.run_program();
        $scope.$apply(); // Have added this line onlye
      });
    }
  }

}]);
```

**Why this is needed?** actually angular has `watchers` concept and when you are doing this complex kind of functionality `watchers` need to **keep deep eye** on variable changes, which is not present auto to achieve speed, but can be added/enhanced manually.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Just out of curiosity, do you know why triggering the empty click event has the effect of updating the variable changes?

Comment: There are a concept of `watchers`. They are watching any change or event occurred. So when you click anywhere on DOM document [in browser] it is an event. Angular quickly re-generate its complete DOM. When a variable is updated with your code, watchers do not detect any change or event triggered.